# Is it possible convert to Purchase Orders from Sales Orders automatically in Zoho CRM?

Tags: crm, zoho

I am attempting to create Purchase Orders  automatically from Sales Order in Zoho CRM. I created custom function, but it doesn't work. I would like to know it is possible to do it or not?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZySQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to use CRM API.